# Function to rotate an array by one

Tags: arrays, c, rotation, function-definition, function-declaration

I'm writing a function that takes as argument an array of integers and returns an array that is left shifted by one -- so { 6, 2, 5, 3 } returns { 2, 5, 3, 6 }.

Here's what I tried, but have issues with pointers probably. Anyone got an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

```
int shiftLeft(int nums[MAX_SIZE]) {
    int i, tmp, size;
    tmp = nums[0];
    size = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        nums[i] = nums[i + 1];
    }
    nums[size] = tmp;
    return nums;
}

int main() {
    int numss[MAX_SIZE] = { 6, 2, 5, 3 };
    printf("%d", shiftLeft(numss));

    return 0;
}
```

It prints `644032`.

Comment: Have you tried printing out size ? Also return type on shiftLeft vs the printf ?

Comment: When you pass an array in C, you pass a pointer to it and that's all. You have to pass the size of the array separately, you can't calculate it.

Comment: In theory you could do `int shiftLeft(int (*nums)[MAX_SIZE]) { ... sizeof(*nums)` but it's better to pass the size separately: `int shiftLeft(size_t size, int nums[size])`

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider this function

```
int shiftLeft(int nums[MAX_SIZE]){

int i,tmp,size;
tmp=nums[0];
size=sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]);
for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
{
    nums[i]=nums[i+1];
}
nums[size]=tmp;
return nums;
}
```

Its return type is `int`. However you return the object `nums` that is declared as the array `int nums[MAX_SIZE]` in the function parameter list.  So the function already is wrong.

Correspondingly this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d",shiftLeft(numss));
```

does not make a sense. To output elements of an array you need to use a loop.

Function parameters having array types are adjusted by the compiler to pointers to the array element types. It means that this function declaration

```
int shiftLeft(int nums[MAX_SIZE]){
```

actually represents the following declaration

```
int shiftLeft(int *nums){
```

It means in turn that this expression

```
sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0])
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof(int * ) / sizeof(int )
```

and equal either `2` or `1` depending on sizes of pointer objects of the type `int *` and objects of the type `int`.  That is the expression does not depend on the number of elements of the array used as a function argument.

You need to pass explicitly to the function the number of elements in the array.

Taking all this into account the function can look like

```
void shiftLeft( int nums[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        int tmp = nums[0];
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            nums[i-1] = nums[i];
        }
        nums[n-1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
int nums[] = { 6, 2, 5, 3 };
const size_t N = sizeof( nums ) / sizeof( *nums );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", nums[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );

shiftLeft( nums, N  );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", nums[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Within the function instead of this for loop

```
for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
{
    nums[i-1] = nums[i];
}
```

you can use standard function `memmove` declared in the header `<string.h>`. For example

```
memmove( nums, nums + 1, ( n - 1 ) * sizeof( *nums ) );
```

Here is a demonstration program where all the code snippets are combined together.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shiftLeft( int nums[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        int tmp = nums[0];
        memmove( nums, nums + 1, ( n - 1 ) * sizeof( *nums ) );
        nums[n-1] = tmp;
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    int nums[] = { 6, 2, 5, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( nums ) / sizeof( *nums );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", nums[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    shiftLeft( nums, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", nums[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
6 2 5 3 
2 5 3 6
```

Based on the function definition it is easy to write a recursive function that will shift to left an array by the specified number of positions.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shiftLeft( int nums[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    if ( n ) m %= n;
    if ( !( n < 2 ) && m )
    {
        int tmp = nums[0];
        memmove( nums, nums + 1, ( n - 1 ) * sizeof( *nums ) );
        nums[n-1] = tmp;
        shiftLeft( nums, n, m - 1 );
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    int nums[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( nums ) / sizeof( *nums );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", nums[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N / 2 ; i++ )
    {
        shiftLeft( nums, N, i );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", nums[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 
6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```